# How Can I Check a Object Literal's Name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

Here I got a object literal which looks like this one below:

```js
var assets = {
  images: {
    'sky': 'assets/sky.png',
    'platform': 'assets/platform.png'
  },
  spritesheets: {
    'dude': 'assets/dude.png'
  }
}
```

And my objective is to create a function which can invoke different functions depends on the type of these assets.

I was thinking of this kind of solution:

```js
function preload() {
  for (var asset in assets) {
    switch ( /* check the asset's type */ ) {
      case 'images':
        // do something
        break;
      case 'spritesheets':
        // do something
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

How should I implement it?

Sorry for my poor use of English, since I'm not a native speaker. ;D

Comment: Your English is fine.

Comment: You probably want to check the *property* name. The object literal doesn't have a name (maybe `assets` would qualify, but that's a variable name and is not acquirable)

Comment: I finally find out a solution which looks alike the solution by @IsaacLyman. Thanks everybody here for your detailed and clever solutions. ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript's `for...in` feature loops over the *properties* (or *keys*) of an object, not the *values*. So you could do this:

```
function preload() {
  for (var asset in assets) {
    switch (asset) {
      case 'images':
        for (var image in assets[asset]) {
          // assets[asset][image] will be an image url
        }
        break;
      case 'spritesheets':
        for (var spritesheet in assets[asset]) {
          // assets[asset][spritesheet] will be an spritesheet url
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused as to why you even want a loop, doesn't seem like there is any need. If you are using a switch, it means you know what the expected properties are called, so why not just access them directly. For example:

```
// Do something with assets.images
// Do something different with assets.spritesheets
```

If you are worried about not knowing if they have been specified then check first:

```
if(assets.images){
    // Do something with assets.images
}

if(assets.spritesheets){
    // Do something different with assets.spritesheets
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`asset` will respond with the name.

Therefore you can do:

```
switch (asset) {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1tekLw5h/

---

However it would be cleaner if you could structure your object differently:

```
var assets = [
  {
    name: "images",
    files: [
       {
          key: "sky",
          path: "assets/sky.png"
       },
       {
          key: "platform",
          path: "assets/platform.png"
       }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "spritesheets",
    files: [
       {
          key: "dude",
          path: "assets/dude.png"
       }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: Thanks for your delicate suggestion on object structure!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `asset` in your `switch` statement as the `for..in` loop within JavaScript will loop over any enumerable properties (which all properties of an object literal are by default).

```
function preload(assets) {
  for (var asset in assets) {
    switch (asset) {
      case 'images':
        // do something
        break;
      case 'spritesheets':
        // do something
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

If you are asking how to enumerate over an object's properties (keys) in a different manner then one way is to use `Object.keys()` to get an array of key names to use to iterate over.

```
function preload(assets) {
  Object.keys(assets).forEach(function (asset) {
    switch (asset) {
      case 'images':
        // do something
        break;
      case 'spritesheets':
        // do something
        break;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Wow, your second method (to enumerate over an object's properties) is a super clever trick! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @YummySushi: I am not saying it is or it isn't, but why do you think it's a "super clever trick"? Is it because it looks more complicated than a simple for each loop?

Answer (score 0):

In response to your question "How should I implement it?" (not to the title question regarding how to check an object literal's name)...

Rather than use a `switch` statement, you could create an object that maps each `asset` to the function you want to invoke for it, then, in your `preload` function, just call the functions on that mapping object.

That object would look something like this:

```
var fnByAsset = {
  images: function () { /* ... */ },
  spritesheets: function () { /* ... */ }
};
```

(If multiple `asset`s share the same function, of course, you'd move the function definitions outside of the object and just reference them from the object.)

And your `preload` function would then look like this:

```
function preload() {
  Object.keys(assets).forEach(function (asset) {
    fnByAsset[asset]();
  });
}
```

I prefer this more functional approach over `switch` statements whenever possible. It feels cleaner to me and tends to be more maintainable and extensible as you add more items (`asset`s in your case).

Comment: Thank you for your nice solution. It inspired me a lot. :-D